# How to pass an Element to a Child Component to ngFor on

Tags: javascript, html, templates, angular, parent-child

It might be easier than I imagine but I found it hard to get an answer googling..

i want to create a dumb component that gets an HTML element (actually another Component) as an `@Input` -or some other way- to be able to `ngFor` on.

If I was to write it down it'll look something like:

**Parent component's HTML:**

`<dumb-comp [element]="<some-comp></some-comp>" [values]="collection"></dumb-comp>`

**Dumb component's HTML:**

`<"element" *ngFor="let value of values;let i = index"></"element">`

I know i could pass a `TemplateRef` as an Input and refer to it with attributes of Components like [ng-bootstrap Tooltip](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip), but i cant seem to figure out how to use that in my case.

Please let me know if I could make my question any clearer and thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for your quick reply Gunter, I must say I'm just a rookie with angular, and it seems like a complicated solution (Was trying to understand it for the past 15 mins and barely got it), maybe we could have a quick chat so i could explain my concrete case?

Comment: There are different options. You can pass a template that contains a component and use it with `ngForTemplate` or `<template ngTemplateOutlet="...">`. It depends on what exactly you try to accomplish. There are many questions and answers related to this topics on SO.